# Running sudo apt-get upgrade error

Tags: apt

I'm new to Ubuntu can anyone help me what is the problem of my ubuntu? I can't download anything because of these errors:

```
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblockfile1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblouis-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpoppler44:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblocale-gettext-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblouis2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpoppler-glib8:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpulse0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblockfile-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libportaudio2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpulsedsp:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblog-message-simple-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpurple-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpurple0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libprocps3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpopt0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libprotobuf8:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libnettle4:amd64': Input/output error

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: What was you trying to download? what did you do ? what command?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If that fails you will have to try running

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package
```

You will have to run that for each package that is giving you an error, for example

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq liblockfile1
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq liblouis-data
```

and on, one by one.

Then again

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: thank you so much .. i'll try it now. i was waiting someone to answer this thread .. :D

Comment: @alden - did that fix it? If not, same error ? See also http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: yep i think that work but when im trying to install an application using "ubuntu software center" i got this error message.

"Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.446'}): org.debian.apt.install-file"

Comment: I really dont why is my ubuntu not working properly. I was running a bit late for my projects that need to be done as soon as posible. Please help me. T.T

Comment: run `sudo apt-get -f` on the command line and post any errors