# dpkg: warning while apt-get

Tags: apt, dpkg

I get these warnings while I do some work with apt-get (install or upgrade). There are lots of them but I think each has something to do with opencv. When I try to install these missing packages it says they're already installed. What does they mean? Thanks for replies.

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-flann-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-core2.4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-core-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-photo-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-legacy-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-imgproc2.4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install each package manually?

Try [this first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644551/running-sudo-apt-get-upgrade-error) in case that doesn't work [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/430682/dpkg-warning-files-list-file-for-package-x-missing) .

```
for package in $(apt-get upgrade 2>&1 | grep "warning: files list file for package '" | grep -Po "[^'\n ]+'" | grep -Po "[^']+"); do apt-get install --reinstall "$package"; done
```

hope it helps